# View overlapping on keyboard popup android in constraintlayout

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout, android-softkeyboard

Below is my xml

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/parentLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/white"
tools:context="com.viewlift.views.fragments.LoginFragment">

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/nativeLoginContainer"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/emailFieldsContainer"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/emailContainer"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/textfield_bg"
            android:minHeight="40dp"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/emailTitle">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
                android:id="@+id/email"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:hint="@string/enter_email"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:paddingStart="10dp"
                android:paddingEnd="10dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/emailTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingStart="5dp"
            android:paddingEnd="5dp"
            android:text="@string/email"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:translationY="10dp"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/passwordFieldsContainer"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/emailFieldsContainer">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/passwordContainer"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@drawable/textfield_bg"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/passwordTitle">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/passwordInputLayout"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                app:boxBackgroundMode="none"
                app:hintEnabled="false"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:passwordToggleEnabled="true">

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/password"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:hint="@string/enter_password"
                    android:inputType="textPassword"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/custom_edit_text_cursor" />

            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/passwordTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingStart="5dp"
            android:paddingEnd="5dp"
            android:text="@string/password"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:translationY="10dp"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/mobileFieldsContainer"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/passwordFieldsContainer">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/countryCodeContainer"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:background="@drawable/textfield_bg"
            android:minWidth="70dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/mobileContainer"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/mobileContainer">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatSpinner
                android:id="@+id/countryCode"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                android:background="@null"
                android:overlapAnchor="false"
                android:spinnerMode="dialog"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/countryCodeArrow"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                android:id="@+id/countryCodeArrow"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/triangle_down"
                android:tint="@android:color/white"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/mobileContainer"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/textfield_bg"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/countryCodeContainer"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/mobileTitle">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
                android:id="@+id/mobile"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:hint="@string/enter_number"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:maxLength="10"
                android:paddingStart="10dp"
                android:paddingEnd="10dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/mobileTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingStart="5dp"
            android:paddingEnd="5dp"
            android:text="@string/mobile"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:translationY="10dp"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/countryCodeContainer"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/forgotPassword"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:text="@string/app_cms_forgot_password_title"
        android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/mobileFieldsContainer" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/forgotPassword"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/forgotPassword"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/forgotPassword" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatCheckBox
        android:id="@+id/terms"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:gravity="start|center_vertical"
        android:text="@string/sign_up_tos_and_pp_text"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/forgotPassword" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:id="@+id/signInButton"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="@string/signin_continue"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/terms" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/separator"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/nativeLoginContainer">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/orLabel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/signin_other_account"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/socialLoginContainer"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/separator">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/fbButtonContainer"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
        android:minHeight="55dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                android:id="@+id/fbImg"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:src="@drawable/login_facebook"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:id="@+id/fbButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                android:text="@string/login_facebook"
                android:textColor="@color/facebookBlue"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/fbImg"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/fbImg"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/fbImg" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/googleButtonContainer"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
        android:minHeight="55dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/fbButtonContainer">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                android:id="@+id/googleImg"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/login_google"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:id="@+id/googleButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                android:text="@string/login_google"
                android:textColor="@color/googleRed"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/googleImg"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/googleImg"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/googleImg" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/mobileButtonContainer"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
        android:minHeight="55dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/googleButtonContainer">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                android:id="@+id/mobileImg"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/login_mobile"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:id="@+id/mobileButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                android:text="@string/mobile"
                android:textColor="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/mobileImg"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/mobileImg"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/mobileImg" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/tveMsg"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/tve_login_msg"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/tveButtonContainer"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/tveButtonContainer"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
        android:minHeight="55dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                android:id="@+id/tveImg"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/login_tve"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:id="@+id/tveButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                android:text="@string/app_cms_tve_log_in"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/tveImg"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/tveImg"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/tveImg" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

This is the output I have
[image]

Now when the keyboard is shown the bottom tv button overlaps with fb button

[image]

How can I fix this?

Comment: You have too many nested `ConstraintLayout`s. And whole upper part is not scrollable.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a view with `constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"`, add a parent scrolling container for your whole view. This should solve your issue.

This happens with keyboards and views having constraintBottom_toBottomOf always as the view only has remaining screen size above the keyboard and below the status bar, hence resulting in the view with `constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"` overlapping the view like you have.